# Adding event listeners to html code retrieved via API-REST

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently learning React JS.

In the project I'm doing, I'm retrieving HTML content from my API using Axios. Here is an example of the HTML code I am retrieving:

`<p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="hover-link" data-background="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/nahled/background-image.png">amset doleres</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tempor, nunc at tempus luctus, risus urna consequat eros, vel feugiat enim erat sed odio. Nulla purus ante, suscipit sed est non, lacinia ornare orci. In congue semper fermentum. Ut lacinia, <a href="#" class="hover-link" data-background="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/250px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png">neque bibendum convallis</a> ornare, turpis lorem interdum augue, in fermentum erat quam non nibh. Proin arcu elit, hendrerit sed felis ut, elementum vulputate metus. Curabitur sed <a href="#" class="hover-link" data-background="https://d1fmx1rbmqrxrr.cloudfront.net/cnet/optim/i/edit/2019/04/eso1644bsmall__w770.jpg">ipsum scelerisque</a>, pellentesque leo ac, dignissim erat. Duis non urna eleifend, maximus justo feugiat, consequat risus.</p>`

I want to add event listeners on all links to later retrieve data-background. I already made a code in Vanilla JS that works perfectly ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/97wo4xsu/))... but I can't make it work in React because I don't know how to manipulate the HTML code retrieved from the API-REST (to add click / mouseover / mouseout / ...).

I'm told to use Ref... but I don't understand how it can help me.

Do you have any ideas ?

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, I finally managed to do what I wanted to do.

I share here a CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/reponse-question-15420864-udemy-cours-react-h2prog-nmbfr?file=/src/App.js for those who might be interested!

Note that this is not the best solution... but it works. It seems that Hooks and/or Ref would be preferable. I will try to improve the code using one of these two solutions.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

PS: A big thanks to @Ky on the Grafikart Discord for helping me.

A+